# Parsing http2 headers and data with Python

Tags: python, http-headers, protocol-buffers, okhttp, http2

I want to parse HTTP2 data with Python

The start of stream is `PRI * HTTP/2.0\r\n\r\nSM\r\n\r\n`  that OK.

The next packet is `\x00\x00\x06\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00`

Next packet is :
 `\x00\x00\x04\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x01`

How can I parse it with Python please .

When I put this data in Wireshark and parse it as HTTP2 I see that as well. But I want to do that only with Python

Answer (score 1):

The start of your stream is the [HTTP/2 Connection preface](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-3.5), that is the start of a HTTP/2 connection. After the preface has been sent initial settings must be established. This is done directly after the connection preface with an [SETTINGS frame](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-6.5). So to parse the packets you must follow each bit(s) or byte(s) and determine what they mean per the protocol. So to help you out, the first bit in your first byte `\x00` is zero (**0**0000000, just a heads up, bits are read left to right in a protocol, but values are right to left), which means that the sender must supply its own settings in the settings frame.

[IETF Hypertext Transfer Protocol Version 2 (HTTP/2)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540)

Comment: there is no script that can parse it? If I care only about data. Is this data can be xor or something like that?